# Is NHibernate Session.Query<T>().Where(expression).SingleOrDefault() loading all objects?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to know, if

```
session.Query<T>().Where(expression).SingleOrDefault();
```

is loading all objects and then filtering them using LINQ, or only loading the one object?

Comment: Log the query that is executed against the database and find out for yourself.

Comment: @servy I followed your advice, and it seems to only load one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*in my experience*, it queries with a `SELECT TOP(1) ...`

Comment: It's going to depend on the specifics of the query though.  It may or may not be able to do this.

Comment: That's correct. Should add "on SQL Server with typically simple expressions"